# Looping through fields does not return some values in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I am very new to programming (I am not a programmer) and I am stuck with what is going wrong.

I have a table (`TEmp02`) with 81 fields but I am trying to loop through only 78 of the fields to get the values and assign it to an public array (`empArray.emptblarr` as variant) declared in a module.

Although the table fields are populated some of the values are returned as Null

```
' to populate the form controls if already the entered empid exists
Dim adocmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim adors As New ADODB.Recordset

'open recordset
adocmd.ActiveConnection = adoconn
adocmd.CommandText = "SELECT TEmp02.* FROM TEmp02"
adors.Open adocmd, , adOpenForwardOnly

Dim j As Integer
    j = adors.Fields.Count - 3  'don't require 3 fields out of 81
ReDim empArray.emptblarr(j)

adors.Filter = "empID = " & Me.cbo_emid

If adors.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Making a new Employee Entry", vbOKOnly, "Employee ID"
    Exit Sub
Else
    ' populate the form controls with the existing latest field data
    adors.MoveLast
    Dim i As Integer
    j = 0
    For i = 2 To adors.Fields.Count - 1 Step 1
        empArray.emptblarr(j) = adors.Fields(i)
        j = j + 1
        Debug.Print adors.Fields(i)
    Next i
    adors.Close
    Set adors = Nothing
    Set adocmd = Nothing
End If
```

This is the main form and I get results of some as null when I do debug.print adors.fields(i) in the loop. This is the result:

```
 2222 
tshering
Null
dorji
tsd
td@gmail.com
 12457845 
 21 
PIC222206282018.jpg
 55 
LIC06282018.pdf
6/8/2018 
6/15/2018 
Null        'This should not have been null
6/16/2018 
 2 
Null        ' This should not have been null
6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2 

6/16/2018 
 2
```

Comment: Why do you think that those field values should not be Null?

Comment: If you get null in some of them, means in the table they appear as empty too.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: the values should have been as it was in table fields, it should have been "PIC111106282018.jpg" and "LIC111106282018.pdf" which are the names of the files saved. But it is always giving me null. Is something wrong with my program.

Comment: But you do have two filenames listed. So what is the difference between that pair of fields and the pair that returns Null?

Comment: oh I am sorry, the null value should have been "HF111106282018.jpg" and "CAM111106282018.pdf". these are different files to be uploaded and saved in a directory and the file names to be saved in the table fields. When I upload it and save the files, the fields are filled with the data. However when I recall them with a employee id combo box, it is not getting the value for some fields.

Comment: The SELECT sql does not have an ORDER BY.  What you think of as "MoveLast" may not be what sqlserver makes as the nth row.  Could you add after Else ..  Debug.Print adors.RecordCount    and maybe also change the Debug.Print i,  adors.Fields(i).Name, adors.Fields(i).Value